# How can I add an undeclared ArrayList to an already declared ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, compiler-errors

I want to add elements to a list that would then get added to the result list.

This is the line of code that I want to use but it is giving an error.

```java
res.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(a,nums[l],nums[r]));
```

The Error:

```
Line 17: error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayList(int,int,int)
                    res.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(a,nums[l],nums[r]));
                            ^
    constructor ArrayList.ArrayList(int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor ArrayList.ArrayList() is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor ArrayList.ArrayList(Collection<? extends Integer>) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

My full solution:

```java
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] nums) {
        int n = nums.length;
        List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();
        Arrays.sort(nums);
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            if (i>0 && nums[i-1] == nums[i]) continue;
            int a = nums[i];
            int l = i+1, r = n-1;
            while (l<r) {
                int threeSum = a + nums[l] + nums[r];
                if (threeSum < 0) {
                    l++;
                } else if (threeSum > 0) {
                    r--;
                } else {
                    res.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(a,nums[l],nums[r]));
                    l++;
                    while (nums[l] != nums[l-1] && l<r) {
                        l++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

I tried creating an array and then converting it to an ArrayList and then adding it but still it gives an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message says it all - `ArrayList` doesn't have such a constructor. It does, however, have a constructor from another `Collection`, so you could use `List.of` to mediate between the integers you want and the list:

```java
res.add(new ArrayList<>(List.of(a, nums[l], nums[r])));
```

In addition, if you don't absolutely have to have an `ArrayList` in your result, just some sort of `List`, and you don't mind it being immutable, you could add `List.of` directly:

```java
res.add(List.of(a, nums[l], nums[r]));
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know of this method as I am just starting out in Java

Comment: You can also use [Arrays.asList()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)).  In @Mureinik's answer it makes no difference since [List.of](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) is being passed to `ArrayList` to make the list mutable.  But the immutability between `Arrays.asList` and `List.of` is slightly different and worth reading about